# Visual Studio 14 - An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Getting this error when I open any Javascript file, I'm using visual studio 2015 community, tried reinstalling, repairing, nothing worked, what should I do?

It tells me to check ActivityLog.xml, this is it:

```
<entry>
    <record>366</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:31.949</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [ErrorListPackage]</description>
    <guid>{4A9B7E50-AA16-11D0-A8C5-00A0C921A4D2}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>367</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:31.980</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [ErrorListPackage]</description>
    <guid>{4A9B7E50-AA16-11D0-A8C5-00A0C921A4D2}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>368</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.042</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [RoslynPackage]</description>
    <guid>{6CF2E545-6109-4730-8883-CF43D7AEC3E1}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>369</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.277</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral]</description>
    <guid>{2FFE45C4-5C73-493C-B187-F2E955FF875E}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>370</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.402</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{D62C17C6-44B3-4E5D-B0AA-1C5536E979D9}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>371</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.402</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.JavaScriptLanguageServicePackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]</description>
    <guid>{D62C17C6-44B3-4E5D-B0AA-1C5536E979D9}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>372</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.402</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.JavaScriptLanguageServicePackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]</description>
    <guid>{D62C17C6-44B3-4E5D-B0AA-1C5536E979D9}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>373</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.449</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.Web.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.&#x000D;&#x000A;File name: &apos;Microsoft.Web.Editor, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos;&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.VsPackage.WpfTextViewConnectionListener.SubjectBuffersConnected(IWpfTextView textView, ConnectionReason reason, Collection`1 subjectBuffers)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.ConnectionManager.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4_1.&lt;.ctor&gt;b__1()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.CallExtensionPoint(Object errorSource, Action call)&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.&#x000D;&#x000A;To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.&#x000D;&#x000A;Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.&#x000D;&#x000A;To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].&#x000D;&#x000A;</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>374</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.542</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{F1A8554A-C492-4871-92E2-7A5EE5940C00}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>375</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.542</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [ServicesPackage]</description>
    <guid>{F1A8554A-C492-4871-92E2-7A5EE5940C00}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>376</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.558</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [ServicesPackage]</description>
    <guid>{F1A8554A-C492-4871-92E2-7A5EE5940C00}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>377</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.574</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{1E863AE9-93F6-42FD-A301-D3391F876208}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>378</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.574</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [CommonAzureToolsPackage]</description>
    <guid>{1E863AE9-93F6-42FD-A301-D3391F876208}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>379</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.652</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{198E76C1-34C0-424D-9957-B3EBD80265FB}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>380</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.652</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Microsoft Visual Studio Server Explorer Package]</description>
    <guid>{198E76C1-34C0-424D-9957-B3EBD80265FB}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>381</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.652</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft Visual Studio Server Explorer Package]</description>
    <guid>{198E76C1-34C0-424D-9957-B3EBD80265FB}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>382</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.667</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [CommonAzureToolsPackage]</description>
    <guid>{1E863AE9-93F6-42FD-A301-D3391F876208}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>383</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.933</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VSPackage</source>
    <description>Should automatically check for an update</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>384</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.933</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VSPackage</source>
    <description>Next update check in &apos;85726184&apos; ms </description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>385</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.964</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{1B437D20-F8FE-11D2-A6AE-00104BCC7269}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>386</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.980</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Visual Studio HTM Editor Package]</description>
    <guid>{1B437D20-F8FE-11D2-A6AE-00104BCC7269}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>387</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.980</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{1B437D20-F8FE-11D2-A6AE-00104BCC7269}</guid>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages*\htmledui.dll</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>388</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.980</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual Studio HTM Editor Package]</description>
    <guid>{1B437D20-F8FE-11D2-A6AE-00104BCC7269}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>389</record>
    <time>2016/02/03 22:45:32.996</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Color Theme Service</source>
    <description>The color &apos;Popup&apos; in category &apos;de7b1121-99a4-4708-aedf-15f40c9b332f&apos; does not exist.</description>
  </entry>
</activity>
```

Comment: In the very last <entry> you have an error with the Color Theme Service. Have you customized colors? Try changing your color theme to a different one to see if it fixes things.

Comment: This would be under menu Tools -> Change Color Theme.

Comment: It's happening with all of the 3 default color themes available

Comment: Restoring Windows and reinstalling fixed it